# Property of skew symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, skew-symmetric-matrices

Prove that the determinent of a skew symmetric matrix of even order remains unchanged if the same number is added to all the elements

Comment: *Hint*: recall how determinant changes under rank-1 perturbations.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a skew symmetric matrix of lets say order 2x2 of the elements [0,a,-a,0] and add it to k times a matrix with all terms 1..

Now generally |A+B| is **not** equal to |A|+|B| but this does hold good for the case stated above, so the matrix with all terms 1, of even order will be 0 giving us the same result...

You can also select a random example and try it out..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.